# Why does action mailer not find any methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

According to this: creating mailers in rails 2.3.14 is pretty easy: http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/

but.. it didn't work for me

I did

```
bundle exec script/generate development_mailer
```

and added a method:

```
  def send_data(data)
    Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

    subject     "An error has occurred"
    recipients  "bugs@myapp.com"
    from        AppConfig['from_email']
    sent_on     sent_at

    body["email"] = data
  end
```

but when it tries to run, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `send_data' for DevelopmentMailer):
```

what's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2.3, the action mailer methods are all prefixed by `deliver_`, so in order to send that mail, you would call DevelopmentMailer.deliver_send_data(data)

It's in the 2.3 documentation you linked, under "Sending Mail".

You're also calling an instance method on the whole class, which is where the `NoMethodError` is coming from. If you really wanted to call `send_data`, you would run `DevelopmentMailer.new.send_data(data)` but that won't actually send anything.